# Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from

Tags: haskell, ambiguous-type-variable

I am a relatively new Haskell user. I'm getting an error `Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from` (variable name) `prevents the constraint ‘(Field a0)’ from being solved.` from GHCi for each variable in my code arising in the call of `tau`. Here are all the relevant declarations:

```
import Linear as L
import Data.Vector (Vector)
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra.HMatrix as HM
import Data.List

find_tau d v0 v =
    let m' = (d><d) (concat (map (^-^ v0) v)) in
    toLists (inv (tr' m'))

d = 2
pk = 16.0
eps = 0.05
s2 = sqrt 2.0
ga = s2/2.0
v0' = [0.5*(1.0 + ga*ga + ga*eps)*pk, 0.5*(-1.0 + ga*ga + ga*eps)*pk*s2/2.0]
v1' = [0.5*(1.0 + ga*ga - ga*eps)*pk, 0.5*(-1.0 + ga*ga - ga*eps)*pk*s2/2.0]
v2' = [0.5*(-1.0 + ga*ga - ga*eps)*pk, 0.5*(1.0 + ga*ga - ga*eps)*pk*s2/2.0]
v' = [v1',v2']
tau = find_tau d v0' v'
```

And here is an example error:

```
Debug.hs:17:8: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘*’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Num a0)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include v2' :: [a0] (bound at Debug.hs:17:1)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance RealFloat a => Num (Complex a)
          -- Defined in ‘Data.Complex’
        instance (Container Matrix a, Num a, Num (HM.Vector a)) =>
                 Num (Matrix a)
          -- Defined in ‘hmatrix-0.20.0.0:Numeric.Matrix’
        instance (Integral t, GHC.TypeNats.KnownNat n) => Num (Mod n t)
          -- Defined in ‘hmatrix-0.20.0.0:Internal.Modular’
        ...plus 15 others
        ...plus 48 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: 0.5 * (- 1.0 + ga * ga - ga * eps) * pk
      In the expression:
        [0.5 * (- 1.0 + ga * ga - ga * eps) * pk,
         0.5 * (1.0 + ga * ga - ga * eps) * pk * s2 / 2.0]
      In an equation for ‘v2'’:
          v2'
            = [0.5 * (- 1.0 + ga * ga - ga * eps) * pk,
               0.5 * (1.0 + ga * ga - ga * eps) * pk * s2 / 2.0]
   |
17 | v2' = [0.5*(-1.0 + ga*ga - ga*eps)*pk, 0.5*(1.0 + ga*ga - ga*eps)*pk*s2/2.0]
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What is the standard way to resolve this? My grasp of Haskell's inner workings is poor, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Standard practice is to give each value a type signature. That would likely solve this problem for you (although I haven't looked at it in detail).

Comment: oh wow, i think that worked, thanks! i added: 
find_tau
  :: Int
  -> [Double]
  -> [[Double]]
  -> [[Double]]
and it compiles (and gives the right answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to ambiguity is to be specific - specify what the types are that the compiler tells you could be one of many types:

```
d :: Int
pk, eps, s2, ga :: Double
```